# Lockless vector

Tags: c++, multithreading

I recently got interested in lockless programming and attempted to write implement a fixed-size mostly-lockless vector ([github](https://github.com/sanjoy/eelish) link).  While it *works*, I'd love to get some feedback from more experienced people if my logic looks buggy or suspicious.

Are there any standard techniques that are particularly useful when testing out lockless data structures?

Comment: Check out the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Lockless? Almost all operations are lockless. Perhaps you meant *lockfree*, which carries with it the connotation of also being thread-safe.

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector` is lockless.  In general, any good vector implementation will be lockless, because the granularity of a vector is too low for locks to be of any use.

Comment: I suspect "lockless" isn't the word the OP was looking for.

Comment: @Flexo But what was he looking for?  The use of "lock" suggests something to do with threading; the standard `std::vector` has all of the thread safety guarantees you would normally want, and it is lock free.